# A question about isometries

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $S$ be a regular connected surface and let $\varphi , \psi : S \to S$ two isometries and we suppose that exists $p \in S$, with $\varphi(p) = \psi(p)$, such that $d {\varphi}_p = d {\psi}_p$. I have to prove that $\varphi = \psi$ in $S$. I have tried to use Egregium Gauss theorem or Minding theorem but I haven't obtain any result. Can you help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: I know very little about this are, but it if I remember correctly, you can use [existence and uniqueness of geodesics for regular connected surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic#Existence_and_uniqueness) to prove the result.

Comment: Define $V:=\{q\in S: \varphi(q)=\psi(q) \text{ and } d\varphi_q=d\psi_q\}$ and show that it is open and closed. Can you finish from there?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!